# How do I make Reminders sync with iCloud on Mojave after downgrading from Catalina?

Tags: macos, icloud, mojave, catalina, reminders

I updated my Mac to Catalina last year but it turned out Wechat for Mac does not work with external webcam on Catalina. I had to downgrade to Mojave but now it seems the Reminders can no longer sync with iCloud unless I upgrade back to Catalina.

Is that true? If so, is there a way to make Reminders under Mojave work with iCloud?

Comment: Do you have an ios device too? That could be causing trouble. ios 13 <-> catalina. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210220

Comment: @ankii yes I do

Comment: Since I am not aware of the problems, write up an answer if the support article covers it, or update the question about what you understood, but still need answers about

Comment: If you are using iOS 13, then you have to use Catalina (or later) if you want to sync Reminders.  Dumb but true.  Since I’m still using Mojave, this is the main reason I haven’t updated to iOS 13.